# MySQL Semi-synchronous replication with Multi-Master

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master, semi-sync-replication

Is it possible to use semi-synchronous replication with a Multi-Master setup?

I've tried to follow this guide to setup a semi-synchronous replication for a master-slave setup: https://avdeo.com/2015/02/02/semi-synchronous-replication-in-mysql/

But I'm not sure how to implement this on a Multi-Master setup.

There are two plugins: one for the master and one for the slave. Since a Multi-Master act as a Master and Slave, does that mean I have to install both plugins on all servers?

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: The idea of semi-synchronous is to wait for acknowledgement from at least one slave and since you would be using master-master so you might have to install both plugins i.e. for master & slave on both nodes. This is because when one master would write the other would behave like it's slave and same goes for the other case. Hope it helps

Comment: @NawazSohail Thank you :) My predicition was right, haha!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of semi-synchronous is to wait for acknowledgement from at least one  slave and since you would be using master-master so you might have to install both plugins i.e. for master & slave on both nodes. This is because when one master would write the other would behave like it's slave and same goes for the other case. Hope it helps

Comment: What happens if you have 3 multi-master servers? Does one master wait until the other 2 servers acknowledge? Thank you!

Comment: semi-sync waits for ack. from at least one slave at a time

Comment: 3-way multi-master is too much a nightmare to contemplate.  If one Master dies, it is very messy to repair.  If you want 3, go with Galera; they have it all solved, even to the point of doing better than "semi-sync".